# Check if the path has duplicates in a list of files?

Tags: python, glob

In the selected path I have a lot of folders in this form:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INB\INB.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INB\INB.shp
```

Need to print the duplicated records

```
 for i in glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/SHAPE/**',recursive =True):
        print(i.duplicated)


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duplicated'
```

Comment: What does it mean for a record to be "duplicated"?  Same file name?

Comment: from the number part of the path till the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is happening becuase your calling `duplicated` on a string object and string don't have that method.
To solve your problem keep a running count of path in a dictionary

```
path_dict = {}
for i in glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/SHAPE/**',recursive =True):
   if i in path_dict:
      print(i)
   else:
      path_dict[i] = 1
```

This will print all duplicated paths in your folder

Comment: This doesn't do anything. why

Comment: if nothing prints then you have no duplicates, you can check the path_dict for all your paths

Comment: The last line path_dict[i] = 1, the key of the dict is your path and the value is an arbitrary number (1 in this case)

Comment: by `= 1` what is happening?

Comment: The ` = 1` is just placed there because dict datatypes are key, value pairs. You could put any number there, ` = 432` and the program will function the same.

Comment: i assume everything is fine here, `+1`